# Why are changes to new answers within five minutes not considered edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

**BIG EDIT:**

(I've redone this question because I wasn't being clear.)

My question relates to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853876/monitoring-file-changes-in-c/2853904).

I saw it and thought the two answers presented were

1. Saying the same thing, and
2. Not very helpful.

So I added my own. As I was doing so, I saw that [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853876/monitoring-file-changes-in-c/2853880#2853880) had changed significantly.

To me, this indicates one of two things:

1. Either the answerer thought he should have added the necessary detail
2. Or, he wanted to get *something* up (like the *FIRST* posts you see on some forums), and **then** edit the answer.

Maybe it's just me, but I don't see how a person with a rep of well over 20k can put in such a short first attempt, then go away and edit it a couple of times and that's okay.

Isn't this just encouraging the *I'M FIRST* syndrome?

At least show some transparency. If the changes are significant, then what's the point of the five-minute grace period?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but you are aware that there's a 5 minute grace period where revisions don't show up in the history, right?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, thats quite normal behavior, for the last update, see *edited time*

<sup><sup><sup>* when did I answer btw?</sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, and the screenshots aren't helping (too large, too noisy). Can you condense it to plain text?

Also as waiwai points out, there is a 5 minute grace period after posting where the original post owner can make changes without creating a revision.