# Deleted questions should not disappear from the Questions list in my Profile

Tags: feature-request, questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

One of my questions was deleted and as such disappeared from my Activity and Questions tabs. There's no way for me to find this question now. It may have been marked as duplicate, but even in cases of deletion I should be able to find it.

**Feature request:** Deleted questions should show up in the owner's "Activity" and "Questions" tabs.

Comment: Do you still have the URL for it?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645)

Comment: And also of interest: [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513)

Comment: Was likely deleted.  Check your browser's history to get the url of it.

Comment: My question about the disappeared question will perhaps… disappear ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco There is no reason that I see for *this* question to be deleted, so no.  While that's technically possible, it won't happen as this question doesn't meet the qualifications for deletion.  Also, this is not a bug, this is the site working as it should; stop tagging it as a bug.

Comment: Seems silly that this question is being downvoted into oblivion.  So long as users can't see their deleted content in their profile, questions like this will be inevitable.

Comment: @Servy it feels like a bug to the person who's question disappeared.

Comment: @KateGregory Sure, but when told that it's not a bug he shouldn't continue insisting that it is.

Comment: @Adam -2 is hardly oblivion...

Comment: @Kate but it's not a bug therefore shouldn't be tagged bug.

Comment: I don't have the address of this question, and I had posted it from my work computer, which I don't have here now. So I am supposed not to be able to see the question in my personal Activity tab ? In this — undesirable — case, the Activity and Questions tabs must at least precise that they omit the questions marked as duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this is very undesirable. However the feature request that wants to change it is status-declined :(

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco The don't omit duplicates, they omit *deleted questions*.  Not all duplicates are deleted; in fact, most aren't.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco if it had been marked as duplicate it would probably not have been deleted unless it was identical to a previous question from you.

Comment: @Doorknob - was -3 before I upvoted ;)

Comment: @AdamRackis But it was -2 at the time you said it was "downvoted to oblivion".  And even so, -3 is *still* not oblivion.

Comment: Your question as written is a support issue. If you want to make it into a feature request, you have to actually name what your feature request is.  Right now you have no actual feature request listed.

Comment: @George — No. If I had been asking for help, I would not have written anything. Actually I was providing help. I wrote this post to request improvement, in order to make the software better. The phrase “even in this case I should be able to find it” is quite clear, it is a feature request.

Comment: @George — In addition, the title and the contents of my post have been changed, in particular by you. The original title and contents of my post were more clearly a request for improvement. I have now edited the title to make it less specific and more faithful to my original request.

Comment: @George — I have now edited the title a little more, to make it closer to the original title and to the spirit of my original request. The problem is not only that my question has disappeared, it is also that questions like mine can — and will probably — disappear again. The editing guidelines say “*always* respect the original author”. Thank you.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco I'll do my best to edit your post into an actual feature request to show you what I mean.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco There. Now it's a feature request. It's still a duplicate. Do you see the difference? one requires reading your mind or inferring what you actually want to happen; and my edit tells people exactly what you want to happen. Explicit is better than implicit, especially since people asking for a similar feature request can't search on implicit.

Comment: @George — There we go. Fine, George, thank you, the improvement request is clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793041/how-to-have-eclipse-run-the-junit-tests-in-their-order-of-appearance-in-the-clas) was deleted by the community user for [having negative votes and no activity for 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).  You have to [suss out the reason by magic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181259/can-the-system-leave-a-deletion-reason-when-it-deletes-a-question).

You can't see your deleted questions [unless you have a link to them or bookmarked them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513).

[I prefer another approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170487/16587) for handling visibility of deleted questions.

Comment: Why don't I see that this answer has been edited ? Usually, the site says “edited” when this is the case.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco I edited it in within the [five minute grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50272/16587).